# Connecting to a server in c++ and collecting information

Tags: c++, string, networking

So I am using QTCreator (5.0/5.1) and I am trying to access a website in a way that allows me to access information.

I have built a gui (as this is faily easy) but I want to know how to go about connecting to a network in c++ for my first time.

so for example:

https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker

I want to get all the information present to me there and store it, the parse it, I just don't know how to connect, to the site.

someone mentioned using the #include  but I'm not sure how exactly to use it as well.

If you could provide an example that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of task you probably want to use the more high level Qt classes to retreive the page and parse the data. Qt provides classes for both HTTP retrieval and parsing JSON data.

- [Network Programming with Qt](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html)
- [JSON Support in Qt](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/json.html)

Read over those documents, have an attempt at writing some code, then ask specific questions, giving the example code you've tried using and what results you're getting.